# AWS EKS ec2 instance reachability check failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks

AWS EKS ec2 instance reachability check failed, knowing that it was working fine yesterday before I shutdown the instance, I can't connect to the instance using mobaXterm nor putty now

some of the system log shows a fail to start Login Service as the following:

```
         Starting Dump dmesg to /var/log/dmesg...

[[32m  OK  [0m] Started libstoragemgmt plug-in server daemon.

         Starting ACPI Event Daemon...

[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Monero miner service.

[[32m  OK  [0m] Started RPC bind service.

[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Resets System Activity Logs.

[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Hardware RNG Entropy Gatherer Wake threshold service.

[[1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Login Service.

See 'systemctl status systemd-logind.service' for details.

[[32m  OK  [0m] Started NTP client/server.

[[32m  OK  [0m] Started ACPI Event Daemon.

[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Dump dmesg to /var/log/dmesg.
```

[image: error1]

[image: error2]

I tried to change the instance type from micro to small to increase the CPU and ram but it didn't solve the issue, also I tried to reboot, stop and start the instance but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The system-logind failure can explain the impossibility of login, but the reachability check fail is symptom of something else.

First, follow the steps on the [official guide to troubleshoot the systems check](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-status-check-failure/?nc1=h_ls).
You can also try to use [EC2Rescue](https://aws.amazon.com/it/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-boot-issues/), mounting the root volume on a separate instance: this should fix every issue on the volume.